# Проблема с запросом get в Angular 2

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, header

В приложении на Angular 2 появилась проблема с запросом к сервлету (Apache Tomcat). Чтобы не быть многословным, привожу код ангуляра, а также ошибку.
Код запроса в ангуляре

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(buf_url_, options).map((resp:Response)=>{ let b = resp.json().data as Route; return b;});
```

Код сервлета не привожу, он банален, формируется JSON как ответ фронту. Ошибка такого рода в консоли

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gbsapod/sapodbridge/getRoute?
 cont=0&foot=0&outstationcode=150000&des…
 &outcountrycode=112&destcountrycode=804&specialmarkscode=58&dispatchtype=1. 
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-
 Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
 'http://sapod_test.gbas.gomel.rw' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Что не нравится Tomcat? Как устранить проблему? Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Спасибо, klutch1991. Все оказалось до банального простым, нужно было включение CORS на Tomcat.

Comment: Помог, принял :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так в ошибке ведь сама причина и описана. По сути у Вас API и сайт находятся в разных доменах.  В целях безопасности,  по умолчанию возможность делать кросс-доменные запросы отключена. 
 Включите возможность отправлять кросс-доменные запросы.  Конфигурировать нужно как раз северную часть,  а не клиентскую. 
Подробнее читайте здесь:
[CORS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

**UPD**
`Apache Tomcat` поддерживает `CORS`, начиная с версии `7.0.41`. Пример минимальной конфигурации:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Более подробно ознакомиться с официальной документацией по настройке `CORS` в `Apache` можете по [ссылке](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).